# PostgreSQL auto-increment aren't incremented using COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in `PostgreSQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                car_id SERIAL REFERENCES car_models (id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

When using `COPY` with the following:

```
COPY cars FROM '/Users/my-user/cars.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Containing:

```
id, car_id
1, 4
2, 3
3, 9
```

Then my `primary key` aren't incremented, so calling afterwards:

```
insert into cars (car_id) values (11)
```

fails with:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cars_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to solve this problem, as below, you can set the start value of the sequence after you copy data into your table (`your_now_max_value`, for example 123).

```
alter sequence cars_id_seq restart with your_now_max_value;
```

The script shell `copy_cars.sh` maybe has 4 lines as below:

```
psql -d database -c"copy cars from xx.txt with delimiter ','"

max_id=`psql -d database -c"copy(select max(id) from cars) to stdout"`

max_id=$(($max_id + 1))

psql -d database -c"alter sequence cars_id_seq restart with ${max_id}"
```

Of course, you can add some alert code to ensure the robustness.Then you can set a scheduler for the script to achieve your aim of twice a month.

Comment: I see, it isn't possible to do dynamicly, so I don't have to know max_value?

Comment: The copy operation is frequently? so what way do you use to copy data into your table ? A shell script?

Comment: The COPY is  not frequently, but it occurs once or twice each month, with 11 tables from export to CSV.

Comment: The way above is OK. You can execute the SQL "select max(id) from cars" every time you copy the data into your table, and then "alter sequence cars_id_seq with max+1". you can just implement a shell script to complete the process.

Comment: Could one to `ALTER sequence cars_pkey RESTART WITH SELECT MAX(id) from cars;`

Comment: I have just written a simple script above for you, I think it would work. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to entirely in `SQL`? Not using `shell` or similar.

Comment: Of course, you can just write the process above in a PostgreSQL function.Then it will totally be a  PG style.

Comment: Or you can just execute the "select" and "alter" SQLs above in a psql client session every time you copy data, it's maybe easier, because your copy operation is not frequent.

Comment: Tried to run `copy(select max(id) from cars) to stdout` in the `psql` client, but got the error: `syntax error at or near "tmp"` guess it should be wrapped differently.

Comment: Yep, when you run in the psql client, remove "copy (...) to stdout", just use "select max(id) from cars" to get the current max id, and then update the sequence restart value by this.

Comment: And the \`copy (...) to stdout\` clause here is just a method to assign value to a varible in shell script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag 'EXPLICIT_IDS' which is used for this purpose.

Try using

```
COPY cars FROM '/Users/my-user/cars.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER EXPLICIT_IDS;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure how that will respect auto-increment when doing import?

Comment: does your file have ids in it?